# Using Environment.SpecialFolder in UWP

Tags: c#, permissions, uwp, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to use `Environment.SpecialFolder` in a UWP application? I am trying to store a database in the `AppData` folder, rather than the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` so that if the user uninstalls/reinstalls, the database will remain.

Currently, storing the database in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` will delete the database when the app is uninstalled. I am aware of `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.SharedLocalFolder`, but that only works if you change the group policy on the target machine, and I obviously will not be able to do that for folks installing from the Windows Store. Is there a way to use the `Environment.SpecialFolder`, or some other way of storing application data in a folder that will not be deleted if the application is uninstalled?

I have not been able to find anything in the manifest capabilities section that would allow something like that, besides storing in the Music/Pictures/Videos library, but the database is none of those things, so I don't think that would be appropriate.

Comment: Did you consider `ApplicationData.Roaming` ? It stays preserved over uninstalls for a certain time period and is automatically synced over different devices in the cloud. One of the disadvantadges would be the amount of data allowed is capped, that's for you to consider, I have no idea about the actual caps involved

Comment: Why not use the DocumentsLibrary?

Comment: `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary` would be ideal, however, in UWP they have removed this functionality from Store apps, according to this post: https://zimbabweandev.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/declaring-document-folder-capability-uwp/

Comment: @pijemcolu thanks for the suggestion - however, since it is a database, it can grow to a large size depending on the amount of usage, so `Roaming` would only work for a short time

Comment: Can you please share your solution with us?

Answer (score 0):

You can let the user pick the location where to save it (in documents or elsewhere), using the FileSavePicker.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker

This would not get deleted when the app is being uninstalled.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform